# Accessing data members through this pointer

Tags: c++, this, shadowing

It is the second time this week I see a C++ codebase where the data members are accessed through the `this` pointer. For example,

```
class Foo
{
    int m_x;
    ...

    void bar() {
        int stuff = this->m_x;  // why not = m_x?
        ...
    }
}
```

You can see this in AmgX for example ([Nvidia AmgX solver](https://github.com/NVIDIA/AMGX/blob/master/core/src/solvers/bicgstab_solver.cu)). What does it get us?

The only advantage I could think of is that if the function parameters happen to shadow data members, it will make it obvious which data you are using. However, I consider shadowing variables a pretty bad practice in the first place...

Anything I might have missed?

Comment: You reduced your example to much. The point here is that the method is a templated one. If m_x is dependent on the template, you have to use this-> to access this member

Comment: Which shows BTW why the `m_` convention is inferior to `this->`. With `m_`, only humans know that it's a member.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks for pointing out the other SO question.